# Unable to Disable Icons

Tags: android, kotlin, service, disabled-control

I want to disable the App Icons (i.e. facebook, instagram) in home screen for the specific time to the user. I dont want user to open these apps for that period of time. I tried different scenarios but couldn't get any approach to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Write your own launcher.

Comment: So, there is no other functionality to achieve this other than creating own launcher?